# Bootstrap 3 separate buttons same size?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I have a problem with my project I am trying to make the buttons the same size and separate them a little as you can see they are stacked like a sandwich. I want them to be in the box but more separate from one and other. Anyone has any ideas or suggestions?

```css
.knappar
{
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 20px;


}

.welcome h1
{
color: white;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 10%;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}

.box {
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid #8AC007;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>


  <title>Project Fairy Tales</title>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
  <div class="welcome">
    <h1>Welcome to Project Fairy Tales</h1>
  </div>

<div class="box">
<div class="knappar">
<a href="bib.html"><button type="button" id="rov" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Ditt bibliotek</button></a>
<a href="store.html"><button type="button" id="rov2" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Affär</button></a>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to set a fixed width for both the buttons and `margin-bottom` for the first button.

```css
.knappar {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.welcome h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10%;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}
.box {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #8AC007;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

/* Added code */
#rov,
#rov2 {
  width: 150px;
}
#rov {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>


  <title>Project Fairy Tales</title>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="welcome">
    <h1>Welcome to Project Fairy Tales</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="knappar">
      <a href="bib.html">
        <button type="button" id="rov" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Ditt bibliotek</button>
      </a>
      <a href="store.html">
        <button type="button" id="rov2" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Affär</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not a problem, Edgar! :)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.knappar
{
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
text-align: center;

}
 
  .knappar .btn { min-width: 130px;}
   .knappar .btn-top { border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; border-bottom:0;}
.knappar .btn-bottom { border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px; border-top:0;}

.welcome h1
{
color: white;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 10%;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}

.box {
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid #8AC007;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>


  <title>Project Fairy Tales</title>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
  <div class="welcome">
    <h1>Welcome to Project Fairy Tales</h1>
  </div>

<div class="box">
<div class="knappar">
<a href="bib.html"><button type="button" id="rov" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-top">Ditt bibliotek</button></a>
<a href="store.html"><button type="button" id="rov2" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-bottom">Affär</button></a>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: glad to help @EdgarAxe

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your css file, and adjust pixel according to your need.

```
.btn {
   margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```